# react native algolia api - how to query?

Tags: react-native, algolia

im using the client api js version of algolia for my react-native frontend.
im trying to query something in a search and i looked at this doc:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/multiple-queries/

but i still can't figure out what is the 'query' parameter, is it just the searched word? or is it some sort of sql syntax or something? its not documented...

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An Algolia query is the search term that users type. It's basically a string. You can also add search parameters to your search query, [as documented in the `search` API reference](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/).

Since you're building a React Native application, I would recommend using our React InstantSearch front-end library instead of using the JavaScript client directly. React InstantSearch consumes the JavaScript client and passes it down to the internal search helper, which takes care of centralizing and orchestrating queries at the right time.

You can get started with the [React Native InstantSearch](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/) guide. As you build your project, you'll also need the [React InstantSearch widget reference](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/react/).

Answer (score 0):

apprently query is just substr of the word to search and there is no special sql syntax or something. i just had a bug with the parameters passing which caused no results to return.